# Could not determine ar interface

Tags: autoconf, unix-ar

Got error when compiling mpich. What does this mean?

```
configure: error: could not determine ar interface
```

Comment: On which platform are you trying to compile MPICH? A quick web search led to a discussion on the MPICH mailing list: http://lists.mpich.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-July/002913.html The solution offered there was that binutils needed to be installed. Do you have it installed?

Comment: I see this when building libuv 0.11 in parallel